# XML-RPC server logging

Tags: python, logging, xml-rpc

I found a recipe do log activities of an XML-RPC server at http://code.activestate.com/recipes/496700-logging-simplexmlrpcserver/

The problem that I'm having is I want to reuse the LoggingSimpleRPCRequestHandler (i.e import it) but I don't know how to correctly set the 'logger' variable. The idea is that

This works (LoggedWork.py):

```
from SimpleXMLRPCServer import SimpleXMLRPCServer, SimpleXMLRPCRequestHandler
from SocketServer import ThreadingMixIn

import os, sys
import logging

class RemoteObject:    
    def return10(self):
        return 10

class LoggingSimpleXMLRPCRequestHandler(SimpleXMLRPCRequestHandler): 
    """Overides the default SimpleXMLRPCRequestHander to support logging.  Logs
    client IP and the XML request and response.
    """    

    def do_POST(self):
        clientIP, port = self.client_address
    # Log client IP and Port

        logger.info('Client IP: %s - Port: %s' % (clientIP, port))
        try:
            # get arguments
            data = self.rfile.read(int(self.headers["content-length"]))
            # Log client request
        logger.info('Client request: \n%s\n' % data)

            response = self.server._marshaled_dispatch(
                    data, getattr(self, '_dispatch', None)
                )
        # Log server response
            logger.info('Server response: \n%s\n' % response)

    except: # This should only happen if the module is buggy
            # internal error, report as HTTP server error
            self.send_response(500)
            self.end_headers()
        else:
            # got a valid XML RPC response
            self.send_response(200)
            self.send_header("Content-type", "text/xml")
            self.send_header("Content-length", str(len(response)))
            self.end_headers()
            self.wfile.write(response)

            # shut down the connection
            self.wfile.flush()
            self.connection.shutdown(1)

class ThreadingServer(ThreadingMixIn, SimpleXMLRPCServer):
    pass

if __name__ == "__main__":

    logger = logging.getLogger('Log')
    hdlr = logging.FileHandler('Log.log')
    formatter = logging.Formatter("%(asctime)s  %(levelname)s  %(message)s")
    hdlr.setFormatter(formatter)
    logger.addHandler(hdlr)
    logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)


    serveraddr = ('', 10001)
    srvr       = ThreadingServer(serveraddr, LoggingSimpleXMLRPCRequestHandler)    
    srvr.register_instance(RemoteObject())
    srvr.register_introspection_functions()

    srvr.serve_forever()
```

and this doesn't (LoggedBroken.py):

```
from SimpleXMLRPCServer import SimpleXMLRPCServer, SimpleXMLRPCRequestHandler
from SocketServer import ThreadingMixIn
from  LoggingSimpleXMLRPCRequestHandler import  LoggingSimpleXMLRPCRequestHandler
import os, sys
import logging

class RemoteObject:    
    def return10(self):
        return 10

class ThreadingServer(ThreadingMixIn, SimpleXMLRPCServer):
    pass

if __name__ == "__main__":

    logger = logging.getLogger('Log')
    hdlr = logging.FileHandler('Log.log')
    formatter = logging.Formatter("%(asctime)s  %(levelname)s  %(message)s")
    hdlr.setFormatter(formatter)
    logger.addHandler(hdlr)
    logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)


    serveraddr = ('', 10001)
    srvr       = ThreadingServer(serveraddr, LoggingSimpleXMLRPCRequestHandler)    
    srvr.register_instance(RemoteObject())
    srvr.register_introspection_functions()

    srvr.serve_forever()
```

If there is a better way to do, please advise. Thank you.

-k

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I haven't properly read you code. Now I see that in this structure it is impossible to do what I proposed. What I would do here is to prepare custom logger at the module level and retrieve it by name in `LoggingSimpleXMLRPCRequestHandler`.

Your are doing part of it in "main": configuring the logger with name 'Log'. Then retrieve that logger in `LoggingSimpleXMLRPCRequestHandler`:

```
class LoggingSimpleXMLRPCRequestHandler(SimpleXMLRequestHandler):
    def __init__(self):
        self.logger = logging.getLogger('Log')
```

and in `LoggingSimpleXMLRPCRequestHandler` methods use `self.logger` instead of `logger`.

Comment: Can you provide more details?

It's actually the gist of my question? How do I pass the logger object to my ThreadingServer?

Comment: Sorry, previously I have misread your code. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: Finally, thank you. It works. 

Instead of doing it in ctor, I set

logger = logging.getLogger('Log') in do_POST(self)