# What are the pieces of a xmlrpc call

Tags: python, xmlrpclib

Let's have a simple xmlrpc server defined as in the following code:

```
from SimpleXMLRPCServer import SimpleXMLRPCServer

def add(x,y):
    return x+y

server = SimpleXMLRPCServer(("localhost", 8000))
server.register_function(add, 'addthem')
server.register_function(add, 'add.numbers')
server.register_function(add, 'sum.two.numbers')
server.serve_forever()
```

which you can connect to via

```
import xmlrpclib
dev = xmlrpclib.ServerProxy("http://localhost:8000/RPC2")
```

With the `dev` object, you cann access the (for reasons of simplicity same)  function `add` in the server, like

```
print dev.addthem(1,2)
print dev.add.numbers(1,2)
print dev.sum.two.numbers(1,2)
```

My question: What are the pieces of those calls? What is `dev` (I suppose an instance of `xmlrpclib.ServerProxy`), what is `sum` in `dev.sum` (a function? a callable? a class? an instance?). What is `two` in `dev.sum.two` ...

For example, the following syntax

```
print dev.add
```

results in an error

```
xmlrpclib.Fault: <Fault 1: '<type \'exceptions.Exception\'>:method "add.__str__" is not supported'>
```

Shouldn't that print something always? What *is*  `dev.add` and the other pieces?

Comment: Where can I find information about those xmlrpc function? Why can't I print them? What attributes do they have? Why can't I do a `dir` of them?

Comment: `xmlrpclib.ServerProxy` sources might be a good start. But why do you need to know that?

Comment: Are you looking for an explanation of the XML-RPC protocol, or how the `xmlrpclib` library implements it's API?

Comment: Because I need to be able to trace any calls to the xmlrpc server. For example, whan I do a call `dev.sum.two.numbers(1,2)` I need to be able to log the exact request, i.e. to be able to reconstruct the full sequence `dev.sum.two.numbers(1,2)`. I started to overwrite the `__getattr__` function, but this does not seem to work.

Comment: I guess I need the xmlrpc API. Any good one your know of? For example, I have figured out that `dev.add` for example has two keys `_Method__name` and `_Method__send`. But what are these things?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to "log" requests, you could (for example) implements a custom Transport in your client.

From the [doc](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xmlrpclib.html#example-of-client-usage) (adapted):

```
import xmlrpclib, httplib, gzip

class LogTransport(xmlrpclib.Transport):
    def send_request(self, connection, handler, request_body):
        # log here.
        print handler, request_body
        if (self.accept_gzip_encoding and gzip):
            connection.putrequest("POST", handler, skip_accept_encoding=True)
            connection.putheader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip")
        else:
            connection.putrequest("POST", handler)

p = LogTransport()
server = xmlrpclib.Server('http://time.xmlrpc.com/RPC2', transport=p)
print server.currentTime.getCurrentTime()
```

Output:

```
/RPC2 <?xml version='1.0'?>
<methodCall>
<methodName>currentTime.getCurrentTime</methodName>
<params>
</params>
</methodCall>
```

and a server error (because it doesn't exists)

Comment: This is interesting! I need to check further, but so far it seems promising. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, `sum.two.numbers` is just the function to be called on the server. On this line `server.register_function(add, 'sum.two.numbers')` you are setting that method to map to the `add` function which takes 2 arguments. All of your server's available methods are mapped to add currently. `dev.add` is just telling the client to run the method `add` on the server. Because you do not map `add` to the actual function on the server, you cannot use it and an error is thrown.

Check out [this example](http://docs.python.org/2/library/simplexmlrpcserver.html#simplexmlrpcserver-example) which includes a custom [SimpleXMLRPCRequestHandler](http://docs.python.org/2/library/simplexmlrpcserver.html#SimpleXMLRPCServer.SimpleXMLRPCRequestHandler) where you can customize it to add logging.

Take a look at this if you are still having problems with the logging: [XML-RPC server logging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5452284/xml-rpc-server-logging)